# Inject component into specific div without Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a "portal" pattern which specifies that an element should be appended to the `document.body`. I want something similar to this, however, it must append to a specific component. My basic layout component would look as follows ([Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/AlexFrazer/pen/NjjJeg)):

```
<div className={styles.container}>
  <div className={styles.header}>
    <Navbar />
  </div>

  {/* Here be the problem */}
  <PortalTarget />

  <div className={styles.content}>
    <div className={styles.leftSidebar}>
      <SidebarNav />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.main}>
      {children}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of rendering to `document.body`, it should find the `PortalTarget` element (ideally only one would be rendered) and then append the `<Portal>` into that DOM Node.

I am specifically having trouble creating and storing a reference to the `<PortalTarget>`, I can't seem to find a good way to do it without redux.

Is there a way to do this in React?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/camwest/react-slot-fill (haven't tried it myself though).

Answer (score -1):

If using an external library issue not a concern, just type "react portal" or "react gateway" on any search engine.

There a few battle-tested libraries out there.

Comment: in the code, they specifically have `document.body` coded in

Comment: Usually reading further the first serp result is good habit. Please read react geteway docs: https://github.com/cloudflare/react-gateway